# Measuring time of a process executing inside a future in Clojure using "time"

Tags: clojure, benchmarking, future

Below is a simplified version of an application I am working on. Specifically, I am interested in benchmarking the execution time of `process-list`. In the function `process-list`, I partition the input list into partitions equal to the number of threads I would like to execute in parallel. I then pass each partition to a thread through a call to `future`. Finally, In `main` I call `process-list` with `time` wrapped around it. Time should return the elapsed time of processing done by `process-list` but apparently, it only returns the amount of time it takes to create the future threads and does not wait for the futures to execute to completion. How can I dereference the futures inside `process-list` to ensure the elapsed time accounts for the execution of the future-threads to completion?

```
(ns listProcessing
  (:require [clojure.string]
            [clojure.pprint]
            [input-random :as input]))

  (def N-THREADS 4)      
  (def element_processing_retries (atom 0))

  (def list-collection
     "Each element is made into a ref"
     (map ref input/myList))

  (defn partition-list  [threads list]
      "partition list into required number of partitions which is equal 
      to the number of threads"
      (let [partitions (partition-all 
         (Math/ceil (/ (count list) threads))  list)]
            partitions))
 (defn increase-element [element]
     (ref-set element inc))

 (defn process-list [list]
      "Process `members of list` one by one."
      (let [sub-lists (partition-list N-THREADS list)]
      (doseq [sub-list sub-lists]
        (let [futures '()
              myFuture        (future (dosync  (swap! element_processing_retries inc)
              (map increase-element sub-list)))]
              (cons myFuture futures) 
              (map deref futures))))) 


  (defn main []      
       (let [f1 (future (time (process-list input/mylist)))]        
        @f1)       
  (main)    
  (shutdown-agents)
```

Below is an example of a simplified list input: Note the input here is simplified and the list processing too to simplify the question.

```
(ns input-random)
(def myList (list 1 2 4 7 89 12 34 45 56))
```

Comment: I have simplified the question

Comment: It should be noted that your `dosync` appears to be blocking indefinitely. If you put a `print` after it, it will never print. I don't use `sync` often enough to know why that would be, but that'll definitely cause problems.

Comment: It seems to be because of `(map increase-element element)`. `element` is is a number, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. You can't `map` over a number. This is failing silently because of your underefed future which swallows the error.

Comment: "element" is a list. I should probably rename that. It represents each partition from partition-list

Comment: No, `elements` is each partition. `element` is each number within each partition. I think you're getting `let` and `doseq` confused. You've probably been looking at the code for too long.

Comment: Look at my edit. Given (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8), partition-list results into ((1 2) (2 4 ) (5 6) (7 8)). This is the sub-lists. Sub-list be each of (1 2),  (3 4) ... You can then map increment-element over sub-list

Comment: You're getting `doseq`'s behavior confused with `let`. Check the value of `sub-lists` with `println` (I just did). If the outer `doseq` was `let`, it would be as you described.

Comment: And if I understand what the root question is correctly, [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/f38c36b5c9521a141e93e0696ac5cb14) might be a better example of what your main question is about. If that's the case, there isn't an easy answer. All the operations are happening via side effects, so there isn't really anything defining what "done" means.

Comment: And [here's a log](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/112dc50e9dfe3bd1ba80f61ee76992f4) showing that `sub-lists` is in fact each partition in turn. Note the "SL" print and what's printed out.

Answer (score 1):

This will have some overhead. If you're trying to `time` millisecond differences, this will skew things a bit (although minute timings shouldn't be using `time` anyways).

I think your example was a little convoluted, so I reduced it down to what I think represents the problem a little better:

```
(time (doseq [n (range 5)]
        (future
          (Thread/sleep 2000))))

"Elapsed time: 1.687702 msecs"
```

The problem here is the same as the problem with your code: all this really does is time how long it takes for `doseq` to dispatch all the jobs.

The idea with my hack is to put each finished job into an atom, then check for an end condition in a busy wait:

```
(defn do-stuff [n-things]
  (let [ret-atom (atom 0)]
    (doseq [n (range n-things)]
      (future
        (Thread/sleep 2000)
        (swap! ret-atom inc)))

    ret-atom))

; Time how long it takes the entire `let` to run
(time
  (let [n 5
        ret-atom (do-stuff n)]

    ; Will block until the condition is met
    (while (< @ret-atom n))))

"Elapsed time: 2002.813288 msecs"
```

The reason this is so hard to time is all you're doing is spinning up some side effects in a `doseq`. There's nothing defining what "done" is, so there's nothing to block on. I'm not great with `core.async`, but I suspect there may be something that may help in there. It may be possible to have a call to `<!!` that blocks until a channel has a certain number of elements. In that case, you would just need to put results into the channel as they're produced.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am also wondering if you deref a future in Clojure, does it not wait for the full execution of the future? And in that case, will I not get the full execution time of the future? Look at my current edit where I attempt to deref the created futures. I also took care of the sub-listing :) issue mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Gakuo It does wait for the full execution of the future. The problem is, since you're back grounding tasks, the future's body returns immediately. Futures do not search through their bodies to find other futures to wait on. The body you give a future is just stuck into a `fn`, and run in a thread pool. Once the `fn` returns, the future is completed.

Comment: @Gakuo And I'll look at your update tomorrow. My brain's fried.

Comment: In that case, let me know if there is a way I can access execution times of those futures operating in the background inside process-list. That is tomorrow :)

Comment: @Gakuo I think there's too much wrong with your new code for me to be able to comment on it. `(cons myFuture futures) (map deref futures))` both do nothing. The first form `cons`s a future onto a list, but then you throw it away because you aren't saving its return value. The latter doesn't do anything because `map` doesn't produce results until the results are requested. Like before, you throw away its return value though, so `map` never runs.

Comment: @Gakuo Don't take this the wrong way, but you might want to take a step back and learn the language better before trying to do more complicated stuff like spawning and trying to time asynchronous tasks.